# Backup of my Droid X

Tags: backup

How (What App) do I use in order to do backup? What is good backup apps out there? I primarily want to save calling logs & SMSs, as all of Applications I can just re-download from Market.

I use Droid X!

Comment: You should probably tag this question as `motorola-droid-x` since that's what it's referring to.  I'd update it myself if I had the rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [BackItUp Pro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/backitup-pro/androidexperts.apps.backitup) successfully -- it's one of very few apps I've found that can backup/restore MMS across ROMs.  [MyBackup Pro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/mybackup-pro/com.rerware.android.MyBackupPro) is another popular app.  I've no experience with it personally though.

Titanium Backup is very nice for a lot of things, but for call logs & SMS, I'm not sure it's portable across ROMs.  It looks like it's simply backing up the sqlite DBs directly.  There's a "Data Migration" option that's been added recently, but it looks like it's a Pro-only feature.  Perhaps someone who's tried it can chime in with their experience.

There's also [Call Log Backup & Restore](http://www.appbrain.com/app/call-logs-backup-restore/com.riteshsahu.CallLogBackupRestore) and [SMS Backup & Restore](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sms-backup-restore/com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore), which are free apps.  They back up to XML files, so should be highly portable across ROMs.

Edit: I had a chance to test the "restore" features last night with my wife's Droid.  I switched her from Ruby 1.1.1 to CyanogenMod 6.1.0, and took the opportunity to wipe her phone and start it fresh.  The Call Log Backup & Restore and SMS Backup & Restore apps worked perfectly.

Finally, there's [SMS Backup+](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sms-backup/com.zegoggles.smssync), which copies SMS/MMS & Calls Logs to your Gmail Account.

Answer (score 2):

[Titanium Backup](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-keramidas-titaniumbackup-xCzz.aspx) is probably the best.  It can back up and restore data like SMSs and call logs.  It can back up the apps themselves too, which is much easier than making a list (or trying to remember) and manually restoring them.  There are others but I don't think any can compare to TB.

Answer (score 2):

As afrazier also said I use [SMS Backup+](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sms-backup/com.zegoggles.smssync) to automatically backup my SMS/MMS and Call Log to GMail. This has the side benefit that it's very easy to access all your messages, etc and search through them when you're sitting at a PC. Great for finding those directions that you know a friend sent you a few months ago!

I also use [LifeSaver](http://www.appbrain.com/app/lifesaver-2/com.textuality.lifesaver2) every now and then, which does a one-click backup of your messages and calls to your SD card. It's very handy to get your history back if you change phones, or need to factory reset yours, or wipe it for any other reason (like putting custom ROMs on).